# Storing semi-structured, key-value based data

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have IoT system where devices send data that doesn't strictly adhere to any specific schema, but there is always "telemetry" object.

```
{
    "deviceId": "SimulatedDevice",
    "telemetry": 
    {
        "temperature": 23.34,
        "status": 
        {
            "health": "ok"
        }
    }
}
```

Telemetry data gets flattened into simple key-value dictionary.

```
{
    "temperature": 23.34,
    "status.health": "ok"
}
```

The key is always string. The value is always string, numeric, boolean or null.

**Question**

What would be the best approach to store this sort of data?

**Option 1**

Use JSONB/JSON for value. You can store anything in value as long as it is valid JSON.

```
CREATE TABLE telemetry 
(
    time            TIMESTAMPTZ    NOT NULL,
    deviceId        TEXT           NOT NULL,
    key             TEXT           NOT NULL,
    value           JSONB
)
```

**Option 2**

Create field for every possible value type. If value is Numeric, I insert it into value_numeric column and make other columns NULL. If the value is NULL, then all columns are NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE telemetry 
(
    time            TIMESTAMPTZ    NOT NULL,
    deviceId        TEXT           NOT NULL,
    key             TEXT           NOT NULL,
    value_string    TEXT,
    value_numeric   NUMERIC,
    value_boolean   BOOLEAN
)
```

IoT data can grow very large, potentially hundreds of millions of rows. Which option, in long run, would yield the best performance?

```
-- Option 1
SELECT * FROM telemetry 
WHERE time >= '...' AND time < '...' AND deviceId = '...' AND value > '75'

-- Option 2
SELECT * FROM telemetry 
WHERE time >= '...' AND time < '...' AND deviceId = '...' AND value_numeric > 75
```

I imagine using JSONB/JSON column (option 1) adds more overhead, but maybe it is very negligible? Are there any general guidelines related to what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Why not store it all as text but include a third field in the data that describes the **type** so you know what conversion is required on the **value** field? Or you could use a bridge-table that stores the type information based on the **key** and still allow all key-values to be text. You could add a new record to the bridge-table each time a new key is added.

Comment: Wouldn't that make filtering data based on value significantly slower since you need to cast/convert to value type?

Comment: Use option2. With that you parse the incoming string once and since you just want to store the data not the structure you need even with option1. But afterward you directly access it. With JSON(B) you need to "soft parse" every access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a best practices blog post about it a while ago. It explains the two formats you presented (narrow and medium, as well as wide), and gives pros and cons accordingly.

I think you might find that interesting: https://www.timescale.com/blog/best-practices-for-time-series-data-modeling-narrow-medium-or-wide-table-layout-2/

Pure JSONB may bite you eventually due to the additional overhead of parsing / extracting the value, and when you add compression into the game, you need to make sure that all deciding factors (when selecting) are indexed, so you only decompress / read the JSONB column when really necessary.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I like the medium table layout the most. Given how I flatten the JSON, the value will always be a JSON primitive type - string, number, boolean or null (absence of any value in string, number or boolean column).